# how to add contents of cursor into hashmap?

Tags: android, hashmap, android-contentprovider

I am using this link http://www.android-app-market.com/call-log-content-provider-in-android-application.html  to get data from the call log content provider my requirement is i want to add cursor values in first hash map then from hashmap to linked list.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking; is this still an issue? Was there some issue with `HashMap.put()` and `LinkedList.add()`?